# Mocking User Interface with RSpec Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

I've been looking on google for an answer but I can't seem to find the right answer.

Basically I want to test out different User Interfaces(Console) in my engine.  I was told to use Mock Classes, and I can't find a straight answer anywhere.

Edit:

Would this be a good way to mock a class(UI)

```
class UiMock

def initialize
  @player_one = true
  @player_two = true
  @board = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
end

def set_move(mark, index)
  @move_set = true
  @board[(index.to_i) - 1] = mark
end
```

Test would be something like this

```
ui = UiMock.new
game = Game.new(ui)

it "creates a game" do
  game.player_one.should be_true
  game.player_two.should be_true
end

it "sets a move" do
  game.set_move("X", 5)
  ui.move_set.should be_true
end
```

Comment: What would it mean to mock a user interface? (Aside from the obvious Metro jokes.)

Comment: Plenty of options available. You could try `mocha` gem for a start. But you need to share more about your 'engine' and your problems with testing for full answers. Can you summarise what is special about your test requirements with some cut-down example Ruby code?

Comment: I was told to create my own Mock class, for example UiMock.rb that mocks the real ui.  the engine simply takes an ui through game.rb ex:  game = Game.new(ui).  I'm not sure if Mocha is the right choice.

Comment: @TakaGoto: Maybe `mocha` would be overkill then. A mock class is just one with the same interface as one you want to replace in the test, usually with highly simplified (often fixed) return values. `mocha` is a tool for constructing common patterns that turn up repeatedly in mock objects. What you could do is add part of the public interface that you need to mock to your question (just input, return value, and how the module under test calls it)

Comment: I created an example above in the question that I tried, and hope that its doing its job.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code reviewing, which better fits at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest mock object might literally be:

```
mock_ui = Object.new
game = Game.new( mock_ui )
# Now run your test
```

Normally you will need the mock to respond to methods that the Game class uses. If you provide an example of one method of the Game class that you need to test, and which methods of the real UI class that it calls, I could extend this answer to show how that might work.

It is not clear whether you are being asked to write a full emulation of a known ui class, or something simpler and tighter for specific tests. Full emulations for mocks are used less often, because they take a lot of effort to write, but the advantage is that the tests become less sensitive to changes in implementation. For example you could write a mock `memcached` service using hashes, and almost completely replicate the interface to `Memcached` class (the functionality you would lose is cross-process caching, usually not something you'd test - at least not in a unit test).

I think you current mock and test could be streamlined a little, as there is code that doesn't seem to be testing anything (yet)

```
class UiMock

  attr_reader :move_set

  def set_move(mark, index)
    @move_set = true
  end
end
```

Test:

```
ui = UiMock.new
game = Game.new(ui)

it "sets a move" do
  game.set_move("X", 5)
  ui.move_set.should be_true
end
```

the reason for removing some of the code is that it was not clear whether or not it was needed. Maybe you *will* need to represent the board and players in your mock UI, but so far the test assertions you have written don't require it. It is advisable to build these up over time as your test and code require them (even alternating between adding one or two tests and adding matching features - just enough on each part to show what needs to be coded next), unless you already have a very clear picture in your head on how all the code will fit together at the end.

Note that `mocha` has a simple pattern for the above test:

```
require 'mocha'
ui = Object.new
game = Game.new(ui)

it "sets a move" do
  ui.expects( :set_move )
  game.set_move("X", 5)
end
```

Comment: I created an example above in the question that I tried, and hope that its doing its job.  one of the methods that game uses is set_move, in which it asks for a mark "X", and an index 5 and sets the move onto a board.

Comment: Yes, that looks in the right ballpark for a mock object, although your code is missing an attr_reader for `move_set`. Your example would be less code in `mocha` so far, but whether or not that holds depends on how consistently the mock needs to respond to the `Game` object's requests. If `Game` needs the UI to remember locations of pieces, then your mock *may* need to do so too (although you might be able to just feed that in consistently from the main test script).

Comment: awesome, as long as I'm on the right track I can figure everything out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Aruba](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba), an extension of [cucumber](/questions/tagged/cucumber).

Also [this page](http://www.awesomecommandlineapps.com/gems.html#tag-testing) is a great resource for all-things command-line.